# Haproxy logging each call twice?

Tags: haproxy, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm using awslogs to send my haproxy logs to Cloudwatch from an EC2 instance running Ubuntu, and it's working fine, except that each log message is appearing twice.

[This post](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.web.haproxy/11149) seems to indicate that it's because log global is in global as well as defaults, but I can't find anything else about it.

Here's the log bits of the current configuration:

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Global settings
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
global
    log         127.0.0.1 local2
    ...

defaults
    mode        http
    log         global
    ...
```

I commented out 'log global' in defaults but I'm still seeing double log entries in Cloudwatch.

editing to add rsyslog 49-haproxy.conf:

```
# Create an additional socket in haproxy's chroot in order to allow logging     via
# /dev/log to chroot'ed HAProxy processes
$AddUnixListenSocket /var/lib/haproxy/dev/log

# Send HAProxy messages to a dedicated logfile
if $programname startswith 'haproxy' then /var/log/haproxy.log
&~
```

Comment: Are you also seeing duplicate entries in the local syslogs?

Comment: Nope -- the syslog is also being sent to CloudWatch, and there's only one entry per log item there.

Comment: If the local syslog has only one line per log entry, I'm not sure how this could be caused by HAProxy... which is sending the log entries to your syslog daemon... right?  The mechanism you're using to forward logs to Cloudwatch... could there be 2 rules matching HAProxy, perhaps one matching severity and a different one matching facility?

Comment: oh -- maybe I'm confused? There's a syslog.log and a haproxy.log; the haproxy.log on the instance is also getting two entries. I've edited the q to include the rsyslog 49-haproxy.conf file.

Comment: In my case I had "log global" in both backend and frontend sections which caused this issue.